# Scrapy email file on completed scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scraped that runs at a timed interval. I want to send an email when the scrape completes. What would be the best method to go about doing this?

I was thinking of writing an extension, but I cant figure out how to access the file that the output was being written to from within the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered hooking the [spider_closed](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed) signal and using the [scrapy.mail.MailSender](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/email.html#module-scrapy.mail) service ?

> **scrapy.signals.spider_closed(spider, reason)**
>
> [...]
>
> reason (str) – a string which describes the reason why the spider was closed. **If it was closed because the spider has completed scraping, the reason is 'finished'**.

Comment: Actually [`engine_stopped`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#engine-stopped) might be a better choice.

Comment: With either, how do I get the path to the output file?